# How can I sum the value between two delimiters in Excel based on the first letter that is between said delimiters?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, sum, delimiter

I'm doing a spreadsheet to divide work among my peers in a Minecraft factions game. The way I want it to work is I've got a cell for each chunk (let's just ignore what a chunk is), and each person's got a letter A-F for example
so the formatting for each cell goes something like

```
A50;B0;C20;D153;E14;F20
A100;B20;C14;D0;E2;F1
```

This extends for a 43 in length and 24 in height. I would like to get the sum of the value of A in one cell, B on another, C on another and so on.
So that I have

```
PlayerA 150
PlayerB 20
PlayerC 34
...
```

I've tried going through here but I think it would either consume too much cells or just crash Excell:
`=SUM(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(LEFT(K67;FIND("B";K67) -2);1)))`

Guess i should post a image, even though i don't need the answer anymore
[image]

Comment: Do you mean all the lines in your example are in a **single** cell?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in cells `A1:A6`:

[image]

`Player A`

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND("A",$A$1:$A$6)+1,FIND("B",$A$1:$A$6)-FIND("A",$A$1:$A$6)-2)))
```

`Player B`

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND("B",$A$1:$A$6)+1,FIND("C",$A$1:$A$6)-FIND("B",$A$1:$A$6)-2)))
```

`Player C`

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND("C",$A$1:$A$6)+1,FIND("D",$A$1:$A$6)-FIND("C",$A$1:$A$6)-2)))
```

`Player D`

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND("D",$A$1:$A$6)+1,FIND("E",$A$1:$A$6)-FIND("D",$A$1:$A$6)-2)))
```

`Player E`

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND("E",$A$1:$A$6)+1,FIND("F",$A$1:$A$6)-FIND("E",$A$1:$A$6)-2)))
```

`Player F`

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND("F",$A$1:$A$6)+1,9)))
```

All of these are array formulas. array formulas are entered not using Enter key, but instead, **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.

**Alternatively** to the above 6 different formulas, you can have only 2 if you put your players names next to formulas. In such case, the following array formula would work for for players A-E:

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$A$6,FIND(B1,$A$1:$A$6)+1,FIND(B2,$A$1:$A$6)-FIND(B1,$A$1:$A$6)-2)))
```

[image]

---

**"The values are 43 in length and 24 in height"** - I am not really sure what you mean. If you mean that your data has several columns and several rows, it is not a problem - just change the array sizes in the formulas. Using the option where you get your names from adjacent cells, you can have these formulas:

For `Players A-E`:

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$D$6,FIND(C8,$A$1:$D$6)+1,FIND(C9,$A$1:$D$6)-FIND(C8,$A$1:$D$6)-2)))
```

For `Player F`:

```
=SUM(VALUE(MID($A$1:$D$6,FIND("F",$A$1:$D$6)+1,9)))
```

[image]

Comment: the values are 43 in length and 24 in height. 
So its not just a collumn

Comment: Okay, I have added some information to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your player ID is only a single letter, in Windows Excel 2013+ you can use the `FILTERXML` function to extract the relevant substrings; then SUM them by starting with the 2nd character:

eg: with Player ID in C2, and `A1:A100` a range large enough to encompass your list of chunks:

```
D2: =SUM(--MID(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,$A$1:$A$100),";","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[starts-with(.,'"& C2 &"')]"),2,99))
```

and fill down as needed.

[image]

*If the ID's might be more than one letter, then we just need to compute the position of the first digit, a relatively easy modification*

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what you mean by

> 43 in length and 24 in height

Suppose your strings are always in the same structure: `A00;B00;C00;D00;E00;F00` in each cell within the range `A1:AQ24` (which is a 43 x 24 range) such as below:

[image: sample range]

Suppose you have a list of players in range `AS1:AS6` and want to return the summed value in the cell next to each player hence range `AT1:AT6`, in Cell `AT1`, enter the following formula and then drag it down:

```
=SUM(--MID($A$1:$AQ$24,FIND(AS1,$A$1:$AQ$24)+1,FIND(";",$A$1:$AQ$24&";",FIND(AS1,$A$1:$AQ$24))-FIND(AS1,$A$1:$AQ$24)-1))
```

[image: Solution]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: ive tried reformating everything to take the first semi collon and tried doing as follows
`=SUM(--MID($K$67:$BA$90,FIND(BC67,$K$67:$BA$90)+1,FIND(";",$K$67:$BA$90&";",FIND(BC67,$K$67:$BA$90))-FIND(BC67,$K$67:$BA$90)-1))`
it gives error 508

Comment: @Imeguras what version of Excel are you using? If you are not using Excel 365, can you please try finish the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter? Also it seems that your data starts with a semi colon in front of the text string, please clarify if this is the case for all strings?

Comment: i feel you're gonna hit my face, but i forgot to mention im using libre office(its was still made originally in excel though)